# 10.14.x App & Applet, Accessibility & Automation Madness

Tags: mojave, automation

Just FYI . . .

The following was submitted to Apple at https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html (788 character limit):

> Greetings, folks!
>
> With every boot into macOS 10.14.x (the best since 10.4.11!), I get
>   multiple alerts asking for authorizations, especially those involving
>   System Events.
>
> The apps and [stay-open] applets that continue to request
>   authorizations are listed in the Accessibility and Automation panes as
>   having full permission to work with other apps, including System
>   Events.
>
> This is a serious challenge for admins who require workflow
>   automation.
>
> I emphatically request that sys. admins be allowed full access to the
>   Automation pane so that we can add apps and applets, granting them
>   full system authorization, and not have to list every single app and
>   applet with which they are allowed to interact.
>
> What is currently in place is, quite honestly, madness.

Since I don’t expect a response from Apple, what steps can I do to get control over managing my Macs on Mojave?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question

Comment: Well, it's a question that has no answer. Perhaps one will come, in time.

Comment: I’m going to take a stab at this. Yes - the question is a bit more on the “rant” side, but I totally understand frustration to have to learn new tools and skills when in the past you could just do what you want on macOS - but the threats to privacy / virus / security are advancing and the old tools and old architecture was showing big cracks and gaps. I hope my answer helps Richard and others..

Answer (score 1):

Managing permissions and workflows on macOS need MDM to be efficient these days.

I would start with a reputable and free MDM to get started liked JAMF now. Once you are MDM enrolled, many management settings are unlocked so that work computers can be configured and managed by pushing profiles to them.

All of the permissions can be set by hand and Apple is making a lot of documentation and changes in this area. I’d start with TCC and kernel extensions one you are done with basic MDM enrollment.

- https://www.jamf.com/resources/a-rose-by-any-other-name-pppc-tcc-user-data-protection-and-you/?keywords=TCC
- https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-now/
- https://support.apple.com/business

Next would be to get Apple Business Manager set up once you’re done with testing JAMF for your needs or evaluating another MDM solution (there are other free / open source to try - but none as easy as JAMF to start and get support from a professional organization).

Good luck learning how to make your life easier with management tools. We’re here for more specific questions once you’ve got the hang of the basics.

Comment: Mike,


I have now explored the Jamf site, etc.; Jamf only seems useful for controlling non-admin. users over multiple Macs.


How does Jamf get me access to, and control over, the Accessibility and Automation panes? Is there anything that can gain such control? Can it stop the endless alerts that ask for permission to work with other apps? Can it stop the “xyz is not optimized for your Mac and needs to be updated” alerts?


If Jamf can do the above, then how does it accomplish such control? Why can’t I do the same on my own? I’ve decades of Mac and UNIX tech. support.


Bless you!

Comment: Mike (bmike): [I ran out of time to edit the above; please allow me to add the following] Thank you for your edit to my post and your suggestions, they are most-deeply appreciated! Blessings, and thank you! (You deleted the closing previously, but it does seem to follow me around.  ;-)  )

Comment: Thank you for the thanks @RichardFairbanks - you may need to go to the full paid JAMF pro for control over all the things you mention, but at least you can start the MDM registration for free with JAMF now.